# Recover indexes primary key

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key

which middle safer for mes  to recover and Sort indexes primary key, avoiding unnecessary update throughout the database? Can you show me any examples?

I just wanna that primary keys were constant and dynamic.I just wanna that primary keys were constraint and dinamic

ps: MySQL Database

---

```
         User's Table
```

||  user_id  || user_first_name  ||    user_last_name

```
 #1            Alexandre               Doria
 #2            Ilya                    Bursov
 #3            Anybody                 Anybody
```

---

So, if i DELETE the #2 row, and INSERT a new row, the primary key of #3 row is duplicated.

My PHP code here:

$user_id_cont = mysql_query("select 'user_id' from user");
$user_id = mysql_num_rows($user_id_cont)+1;

Comment: primary keys are always sorted in mysql, what do you mean by recover?

Comment: Always after deleting a row, a primary key is duplicated. How to get the index of subsequent primary key is equal to the index of the last row deleted?

Comment: I'm not sure that you use terminology properly, you cannot get index of subsequent primary key. You can get value of new autoincremented primary key, autoincremented keys are not duplicated if rows are deleted

Comment: And if I put in user_id AUTO_INCREMENT column, how should I do so that the indexes do not "jump" after rows are deleted? I think that shold be more easy

Comment: what do you mean by "jump"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It absolutely wrong to calculate primary keys as it done in your code

First of all - change user_id column to be primary key (it will be unique too then), also set it to be auto_increment, so your table create statement must be:

```
create table sample_users (
`user_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment,
`first` varchar(255),
`last` varchar(255),
primary key (`user_id`)
);
```

next, you need to insert data into your table, so you can just insert it:

```
INSERT into `sample_users` (`first`, `last`) values('fname', 'lname');
INSERT into `sample_users` (`first`, `last`) values('fname2', 'lname2');
...
```

mysql will generate appropriate user_id for each row, and even if you delete some of them - mysql still will provide you with unique values

additional case is - if you need to know what id is generated by mysql, you can use PHP [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) or MySQL [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) functions for that

just for notice: wrong method, but it will work for "school project", change your code to:

```
$user_id_cont = mysql_query("select max('user_id') from user");
$user_id = mysql_fetch_array($user_id_cont, MYSQL_NUM);
$user_id = $user_id[0]+1;
```